# akka scheduler avoiding recursion

Tags: scala, recursion, akka

Out of curiousity, how do you avoid an infinite recursion involving a `Future` return type, as in this example? the recursion *should be* infinite, but rather how does this avoid an infinite number of threads being accumulated?

```
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import scala.concurrent.blocking
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val system = ActorSystem("MySystem") // make global if more things hinge on the actor system

  val interval = Configuration.dbSyncIntervalSecs

  private def acquireLoop: Future[Any] = {
    Future { 
      blocking { 
        println("about to sync from database")
        acquire
        system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(interval seconds)(acquireLoop)
      }
    }
  }
```

I would like to somehow flatten this, but `@tailrec` would not apply. Maybe I should not use the `Future` abstraction for dispatching a blocking action on a thread, but still this makes a nice thought drill doesn't it..

Comment: Why is this code a problem?  I only see this piece of code consuming one thread at a time.  It does it's job first before rescheduling itself via `scheduleOnce`, so even if the `aquire` part takes multiple seconds, it won't be re-running on top of itself since you only reschedule after that part is done.  Also, why is @tailrec important here?  Tail call optimization only helps if you expect a long call stack, which you won't have here as you are using scheduled futures.

Comment: This isn't actually recursive: there is only one instance of `acquireLoop` on stack at any time.

Comment: Thanks guys, indeed I missed that, I should probably delete this :)